Can a particle moving vertically upwards in space with constant velocity escape the earths orbit?
Let’s assume that a particle is moving vertically upwards towards space, said particle is having a constant velocity regardless of all forces acting. I repeat NO FORCES HAVE ANY KIND OF EFFECT ON ITS VELOCITY {hypothetically obviously}, so the question is will it exit the gravitational field of earth given infinite amount of time?

"said particle is having a constant velocity regardless of all forces acting" - with respect to what?

Since the premise of the question denies gravity, the rest of it makes no sense.

Since there is no gravity any vertical velocity will escape the Earth's non-existent gravitational field.

@Filip Milovanović : "with respect to what?" ==[  With respect to its distance from Earth. That speed never changes, despite the weather.

Gravity obeys the inverse square law, so there's no distance where the gravitational field strength of a body is zero.

I think the spirit of this question is quite obvious, and I was seconds away from posting my answer when it was closed, so I'm going to abuse my moderator superpower and reopen the question unilaterally.

@LTurner I see a little problem with that

Let's make the question slightly less fantastical by proposing a mechanism.  Suppose there is a spiral staircase that extends vertically away from the Earth forever.  You could put the axis of the staircase at one of Earth's poles, if you didn't want to worry about Earth's rotation exerting forces on it.  You climb the staircase at one step per second.  Do you eventually escape from Earth's gravity?
The answer depends a little bit on quite what "escape" means.  In Newtonian gravity and general relativity, there isn't any distance where the gravitational attraction between two masses goes to zero.  Generally we are talking about the total mechanical energy of the system,
$$
E = T + U = \frac12 m v^2 - m\frac{GM}{r}
$$
where the kinetic energy $T = \frac12 mv^2$ is associate with the motion of the particle with mass $m$, and the potential energy $U=-G\frac{Mm}{r}$ comes from the gravitational attraction between the particle with mass $m$ and the planet with larger mass $M$.
Usually in these problems we distinguish "bound" from "unbound" systems using the sign of the total energy $E$.  If the total energy is negative, $GM/r > v^2/2$, there is some maximum $r$ where energy conservation requires $v=0$, and the particle can't climb any higher than this.  But if the total energy is positive, $GM/r < v^2/2$, then as the particle approaches $r\to\infty$ it will still have kinetic energy "left over," and the particle will have finite speed even where the gravitational attraction has become negligible.  The speed which separates these "bound" versus "unbound" conditions, $GM/r = v_\text{escape}^2/2$, is called the "escape velocity."  Notice that the same mass $M$ has different escape velocities at different altitudes $r$.
Most people who climb stairs near Earth's surface do so at less than the local escape velocity, which is about eleven kilometers per second.  But if you kept climbing, patiently, you could in principle reach an altitude where your climbing speed is more than the escape velocity.  Whether your body contains enough chemical energy to accomplish this feat is a more complicated question, which probably turns out to involve the rocket equation.

Good answer. It will probably be beneficial to highlight the differences between the first part, which assumes continuous energy input from an external agent to maintain constant velocity, and the second part, which assumes the object moving freely with no energy input from an external agent.

I had a paragraph about that, but it got eaten while the question was briefly closed, and I didn't rewrite it. The gist was to imagine jumping up from one step to the next with constant launch speed, and eventually being able to use that same jump to skip steps while maintaining the same average speed. There comes an altitude where your jump speed is more than the escape velocity, but you still always need some additional kinetic energy to maintain constant velocity.

The only particles that have a constant velocity where no forces of any kind have an effect on its velocity are massless particles such as a photon. Those particles move at the speed of light.
An upward photon will be red shifted as it moves away from Earth. But it will not slow down, and it will not reach a maximum altitude. It will keep moving upward forever unless it hits something. In this sense, it escapes Earth's gravity.
But it will not escape in the sense that it will get past Earth's gravitational field. The field extends outward to infinite distance.

Replace the particle with a rocket that continually adjusts its thrust to compensate for the force of gravity and maintain constant velocity. Given infinite time it will  obviously escape the Earth's gravitational field (i.e. so far away that the field is negligible), because at any instant it is moving away from the Earth.

==[ THE ANSWER YOU MIGHT EXPECT:
Yes, if its (constant) velocity exceeds the escape velocity of Earth, right from the start. Otherwise, after an exponentially long amount of time, it will fall back to Earth eventually
... if and only if it ever stops being pushed!
==[ THE CORRECT ANSWER:
The required escape velocity isn't from the surface of the Earth, it's from the center of the Earth. If you can get really close to the center and still be outside of it, like if the Earth was a black hole, the escape  velocity would be huge.
If you could get 1/3 of an inch away from the center of the Earth, the escape velocity would be c. That's called the Swartzchild radius for the mass of the Earth, but the names of things don't matter.
But when your distance from the center increases as you leave the surface of the Earth, the escape velocity -- the speed so you'll never fall back down -- gradually gets less and less the farther away you go.
Floating in the ISS, gravity is still 90% of what it is on Earth. You just never stop falling, that's all.
The escape velocity decreases with the square of the distance to the center of the Earth (not from the surface). At a distance of 4,000 miles (i.e. the surface), the escape velocity is [whatever it is].
That critical distance is determined by whatever constant velocity you're starting off with. Farther than that, whatever is pushing it can release it, and the object will never fall back to Earth.
Note! The escape velocity approaches zero but but only drops to zero at infinite distance. So, interestingly(?), at ANY distance, you must release the object while it's moving.
Can you see why?
If you release it floating at rest with respect to the Earth, it will eventually fall back down -- no matter how far away you are!
Even cooler, If you drop an object from an infinite distance, it will hit any event horizon of any size with momentum equal to the E=Mc² mass-energy of the object.
